# Converting exponential values to negative intege

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am trying to convert exponential values to the integer from column A('exp_col') and I am getting those values converting to negative column number in column C ('Converting_to_int')

[image]

Below are the syntax i have used to convert

```
df['Converting_to_int'] = df['exp_col'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

I need the values as shown in column B ('Original_values) from column A.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How working `df['Converting_to_int'] = df['exp_col'].fillna(0).astype(np.int64)` ? What is your pandas version?

Comment: its : print(pd.__version__)
0.25.1

Comment: `numpy` integers are not like Python integers.  They aren't infinitely large.  A `numpy` integer field is 32 bits wide.  Your number is larger than 32 bits, so you get an overflow.